# Checking at least two columns SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I have a table, which has 5 boolean columns, as well as a few other columns, like so:

```
rowid | bool1 | bool2 | bool3 | bool4 | bool5 | other1 | other2 | other3 |
    1 |     1 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |      5 |     34 |  'foo' |
    2 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     1 |     0 |      7 |     42 |  'bar' |
    3 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |     12 |      7 | 'blah' |
    4 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |      5 |     34 | 'blah' |
```

I want a way to select all the rows in which at least 2 of all the bool columns are True.
In this case: rows 1, 2 and 3 but not 4.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A nearly identical question was asked recently.  The answer was to add up all the boolean columns (after casting each column first to an integer, if needed) and see if the sum is greater than two.

Comment: Ah yes, that would work. Thanks.